# spray-json can't find JsonReader for type List[T]

Tags: scala, spray-json

I'm creating custom json readers for case classes but it can't find implicit JsonReader type class for List[T] which is used in other case class.

When I checked DefaultJsonProtocol, it has implicit format for collections already;

```
  implicit def listFormat[T :JsonFormat] = new RootJsonFormat[List[T]] {
    def write(list: List[T]) = JsArray(list.map(_.toJson).toVector)
    def read(value: JsValue): List[T] = value match {
      case JsArray(elements) => elements.map(_.convertTo[T])(collection.breakOut)
      case x => deserializationError("Expected List as JsArray, but got " + x)
    }
  }
```

Here is the simplified code;

```
case class Test(i: Int, d: Double)
case class ListOfTest(t: List[Test])

trait TestResultFormat extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  import CustomFormat._

    implicit object TestJsonFormat extends RootJsonReader[Test] {

    override def read(json: JsValue): Test = {

      val jsObject = json.asJsObject
      val jsFields = jsObject.fields

      val i = jsFields.get("i").map(_.convertTo[Int]).getOrElse(0)
      val d = jsFields.get("d").map(_.convertTo[Double]).getOrElse(0d)

      Test(i, d)
    }
  }

  implicit object ListOfTestJsonFormat extends RootJsonReader[ListOfTest] {

    override def read(json: JsValue): ListOfTest = {

      val jsObject = json.asJsObject
      val jsFields = jsObject.fields

      val tests = jsFields.get("hs").map(_.convertTo[List[Test]]).getOrElse(List.empty)

      ListOfTest(tests)
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the errors;

```
Error:(230, 53) not enough arguments for method convertTo: (implicit evidence$1: spray.json.JsonReader[List[com.xx.Test]])List[com.xx.Test].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
      val tests = jsFields.get("hs").map(_.convertTo[List[Test]]).getOrElse(List.empty)
                                                    ^
Error:(230, 53) Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for List[com.xx.Test]
      val tests = jsFields.get("hs").map(_.convertTo[List[Test]]).getOrElse(List.empty)
                                                ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is related to the fact that the `JsonReader` for `List[T]` in `DefaultJsonProtocol` is a `RootJsonFormat` (not a `RootJsonReader`), which basically means you can read it and also write it. So, when you try to read a `List[Item]`, it's expected that you are also able to write `Item`s. So, you could use `RootJsonFormat` instead and throw an exception in case you try to write it (since you don't support it). For example:

```
import spray.json._

implicit object TestJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Test] {

  override def read(json: JsValue): Test = {

    val jsObject = json.asJsObject
    val jsFields = jsObject.fields

    val i = jsFields.get("i").map(_.convertTo[Int]).getOrElse(0)
    val d = jsFields.get("d").map(_.convertTo[Double]).getOrElse(0d)

    Test(i, d)
  }

  override def write(obj: Test): JsValue = serializationError("not supported")
}
```

If you are aware of a clean solution involving only the readers, please do let me know because I ran into this problem myself and couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have just learned it from github issue. For the clean solution check my answer, I don't think its quite clean but I don't want to override write method always because we have lots of custom formatters, it's quite overhead so I created a base trait to do that.

Comment: I see :) I had this problem long ago and I kind of got used to just overriding the (unused) write method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have learned that limitation comes from spray-json:

> spray-json 's type class infrastructure is build around the (Root)JsonFormat type, not the (Root)JsonReader. So you'll indeed have to provide a "Format" even if you are just reading.

[Check here.](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/116#issuecomment-55567764)

To overcome issue; I created another trait extends RootJsonFormat instead of reader and overrides write method with basically not implemented method.

```
trait EmptyWriterFormat[T] extends RootJsonFormat[T] {
  override def write(o: T): JsValue = ???
}
```